# router onRouteGenerated: Only in child widget instead of setting it in material app widget

Tags: flutter

I want to have a bottom navigation bar and use named routes (mainly for flutter web).

Therefore I always need the tab-bar scaffold as a base and have a navigator widget as its body for the content. This is working fine.
The problem is that if I move to the second tab and reload the app in flutter web, I get this error message:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER FRAMEWORK ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following message was thrown:
Could not navigate to initial route.
The requested route name was: "/2"
There was no corresponding route in the app, and therefore the initial route specified will be
ignored and "/" will be used instead.
```

I know, I get this error message because there are no routes / onRouteGenerated specified on the material app level. But I rather don’t want to specify it there because I always need the TabBarWidget and don’t want to replace it with a different widget, instead I want to show the content inside of it.

Therefore the question is: Is it possible to delegate the onRouteGenerated „call“ to a child navigator, to the one in the body of the tabBarWidget?
Or is there a better solution?

Example Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [
        DefaultMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        DefaultCupertinoLocalizations.delegate
      ],
      home: TabBarWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class TabBarWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  TabBarWidgetState createState() => TabBarWidgetState();
}

class TabBarWidgetState extends State<TabBarWidget> {

  int currentIndex = 0;
  final _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        onTap: (number) => _itemChanged(number),
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.mail), title: Text("1")),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.mail), title: Text("2")),
        ],
      ),
      body: Navigator(
        key: _navigatorKey,
        initialRoute: "/1",
        onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
      ),
    );
  }


  _itemChanged(int number) {
    currentIndex = number;
    setState(() {});

    String path;

    switch (number) {
      case 0:
        path = "/1";
        break;
      case 1:
        path = "/2";
        break;
      default:
        path  = "/1";
        break;
    }
    _navigatorKey.currentState.pushReplacementNamed(path);
  }
}

class RouteGenerator {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/1':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => ScreenOne(), settings: settings);
      case '/2':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => ScreenTwo(), settings: settings);
      default:
        return _errorRoute();
    }
  }

  static Route<dynamic> _errorRoute() {
    return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Error'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('ERROR'),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}

class ScreenOne extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
    );
  }
}

class ScreenTwo extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.yellow,
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: So If I  understand right, your problem will be solved if you can use your own navigator instead of the default one, check this package : https://pub.dev/packages/custom_navigator/versions/0.1.1#-readme-tab-

Comment: Unfortunately it is not solved with that package, because I already use an additional navigator in the example so the functionality stays the same.
The problem is that only the root navigator tries to resolve the url / named path. 
But I need this to be done by my custom navigator in the tabbar widget. 
This problem only occurs on a reload in the flutter web app, changing it via _itemChanged(1) is working fine